# Partitioning Master Detail Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, database-partitioning

I Use `SQL Server 2008 R2` and want to partitioning Master table and Detail table together. How can I partitioning Detail table by `MasterTypeID` field in Master table.

My Partition Function is :

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION MasterTypeFN(int)
AS 
RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (1,2,3)
```

My Partition Schema is :

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME MasterTypeScheme 
AS 
PARTITION MasterTypeFN 
TO ([FG1], [FG2], [FG3], [PRIMARY])
```

My Master Table Structure is :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Master  
(
   [MasterID] [int] NOT NULL,
   [MasterTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
   ...
) 
ON MasterTypeScheme (MasterTypeID)
```

My Detail Table Structure is :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Detail
(
   [DetailID] [int] NOT NULL,
   [MasterID] [int] NOT NULL,
   ...
)
```

I want to Partitioning Detail table with regard to master partition. In other word I want to save Master table record and related details in one filegroup.

Comment: Are these tables going to be HEAPs or will they have a clustered index? If they are a clustered table, the partitioning column will need to be part of the clustered index or the primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define `MasterTypeID` column in Detail table and define permission on it to disable update this column. and create trigger on `Master` table to sync `MasterTypeID` column in `Master` table with `MasterTypeID` column in `Detail` table.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is possible. You need to copy the value of `MasterTypeID` to each row of the `Detail` table so that the partition function can be applied to `Detail`.

Create a new column `Detail.MasterTypeID` and fill that column appropriately. Either in your application code or using a trigger in the database.

After the column is correctly filled you can apply the partition function.

Comment: thanks for your answer. how can I synchronize `Detail.MasterTypeID` and `Master.MasterTypeID` together?

Comment: `Detail.MasterTypeID` must be read only column and update only when `Master.MasterTypeID` column changed. also `Detail.MasterTypeID` must be equal to related `Master.MasterTypeID` and must be change automatically when `Master.MasterTypeID` changed.

Comment: Yes exactly right. I suggest you create an `AFTER` trigger in the `Master` table `FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`. You can use the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` pseudo-tables in that trigger to update all `Detail` rows accordingly. This is too much code to type here, but it is straight forward.

Comment: +1 If I don't find better way; certainly use this method for partitioning my master-detail tables.